# Property 'storeOutputAutomatically' not valid in version 48.0

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, metadata-api, visual-flows, api-version

I am trying to deploy a flow to a sandbox and I am getting the error

> Property 'storeOutputAutomatically' not valid in version 48.0

The `sourceApiVersion` specified in my `sfdx-project.json` file is 48.0. The `<apiVersion>` in our `package.xml` is 47.0. However, this flow has contained the `<storeOutputAutomatically>` tag for the last month, and has not failed validation for this sandbox. The sandbox has not been refreshed. We have not made changes to the package.xml version or the sourceApiVersion in the `sfdx-project.json` file in at least a month.

Also, the documentation for the `storeOutputAutomatically` field on the FlowActionCall metadata type says the field is available in API version 48.0 and later:
[image: documentation]

What could be causing this sudden validation failure?

Comment: what happens if you change apiVersion to 48.0 in package.xml as well? The error may be misleading.

Comment: I'll try that out and report back here, however the package.xml `apiVersion` and sfdx-project.json `sourceApiVersion` did not match before, and we did not hit this error up until today, deploying the flow to the same sandbox with the `< storeOutputAutomatically>` tag.

Comment: Just updated the package.xml `apiVersion` to 48.0 and it did not solve the problem, still getting the same error. Will file a case with Salesforce.

Comment: Can you add some sample metadata with which we can reproduce the error so we can hand off the bug to metadata API team?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We figured out the problem -- there was a subflow added to the flow, that had `<storeOutputAutomatically>true<storeOutputAutomatically>`. Prior to yesterday, the only elements that had the `<storeOutputAutomatically>` tag were record creates, record lookups and 'show toast' actions. We fixed the problem by checking the 'Manually assign variables' box in the parent flow that calls the subflow.

I guess `storeOutputAutomatically` is not yet supported for subflows.

Thank you for your quick reply and for looking into this, Mohith.

Answer (score 1):

The `package.xml` version must be kept equal to the api version specified in the `sourceApiVersion` to make sure everything is on 48.0.

If you are still getting exception then this might be a salesforce bug that needs more investigation.

UPDATE

`storeOutputAutomatically` is not yet supported for subflows as per investigation.

Comment: We ran into this issue but seems like standard changeset deployment is not giving this error though. Any idea why package.xml deployment is throwing this error but not changeset?