# Metadata retrieve works, but deploy fails

Tags: api, salesforcedx, visual-workflow, deployment, metadata

Org API=49.
Process Builder flow API=49,
I retrieve flow with no error, then try to deploy it back to the same Org without any changes and get an error:

```bash
C:\2\force-app\main\default>sfdx force:source:retrieve -u MS1 -p flows/Opportunity_Automation_Processes.flow-meta.xml
=== Retrieved Source
FULL NAME                         TYPE  PROJECT PATH
────────────────────────────────  ────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Opportunity_Automation_Processes  Flow  force-app\main\default\flows\Opportunity_Automation_Processes.flow-meta.xml

C:\2\force-app\main\default>sfdx force:source:deploy -u MS1 -p flows/Opportunity_Automation_Processes.flow-meta.xml
Job ID | 0AfL000000yngquKAA
SOURCE PROGRESS | ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ | 0/1 Components
TYPE   PROJECT PATH                                                                 PROBLEM
─────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Error  force-app\main\default\flows\Opportunity_Automation_Processes.flow-meta.xml  Property 'filterLogic' not valid in version 49.0 (2736:20)
ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Deploy failed.
```

Why it gives me this property and doesn't get it back?

Comment: Does the Flow contain any subflows? What is the API version specified in your `package.xml`? Is it 49.0? [This error can be caused by a mismatch of API versions in the org vs. your deployment config.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318091/property-storeoutputautomatically-not-valid-in-version-48-0)

Comment: sfdx-project.json
  "sourceApiVersion": "49.0"

Comment: Suggest raise a case with Salesforce support. Did you try other versions to push it back?

Comment: changing sfdx-project.json "sourceApiVersion": "50.0" solve this issue.